# How use geofield_openlayers in custom module

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, location

I'm writing a drupal custom module, in my form I need a geofield with openlayers map widget.
I can create a geofield_openlayer by using Content type, but I don't know how can I create the field in my custom module... which form type do I have to use?

This code don't works

```
$form['geofield_openlayers'] = array(
'#title' => 'geofield_openlayers',
'#type' => 'geofield_latlon',
);
```

Only geofield_bounds, geofield_proximity, geofield_latlon types works... but maps is not displayed.

Thank you.